# Delete all files from the database and disk that is not in the httpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, httprequest

I have a httpRequest that takes e.g 5 files and saves them to a folder on the server. E.g Image1.png, Image2.png, Image3.png. I add them to the database with the same file name in another function, eg I have a column with Image1.png, Image2.png, Image3.png.

```
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    string DecodedFile = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(postedFile.FileName.ToString());
                    string fileNameToLower = DecodedFile.ToLower();
                    string fileName = char.ToUpper(fileNameToLower[0]) + fileNameToLower.Substring(1);

                    var folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(IMAGEFOLDER);
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(folder, fileName);
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                }
            }
```

If a file is **not** in the request, I want delete the file from the server and from the database. Eg. I have the file names Image1.png, Image2.png, Image3.png in the database and on the server. If I get a httpRequest with the files Image1.png and Image3.png (Image2.png is not in the request) I want to delete Image2.png from the server and from the database.

The problem is to delete something that is **not** in the request. The opposite would have been easy. I quess I have to compare the files in the request with the file names in the database in some way. I only have images in that table so it is ok to delete everything that is not in the request. I can clean the table before each request but it feels stupid since my requests is very frequent (new files every 5 minute).

Comment: You need to make some effort to solve this on your own.  What have you tried?

Comment: why don't you add the filename from the request into a List<T> then write some sql IF NOT Exist or IF Exist depending on your logic and pass in the List<T> as a string array or you can run it in a foreach loop.. this doesn't sound too difficult based on the code you have, does it work for posting the files to the server..? if so then where is the code that handles the Deletion from Sql DB..?

Comment: You said that you have a "group" of images coming into your request. Are these images related/grouped by some kind of Id? If so, you can query the database to get all file names of the Id of the request. Than it's easy to compare which images are not present and you can delete them from db/server.